cpanel 503 server error when deploying node js application
After deploying node js app in cpanel it is giving me 503 service unavailable error. I am using 16.20.2 version same in both local machine and in cpanel also.
This is my server .js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
const priceRoutes = require("./routes/priceRoutes");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/orderRoutes");
const serviceRoutes = require("./routes/serviceRoutes");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;



app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api", priceRoutes);
app.use("/api", orderRoutes);
app.use("/api", serviceRoutes);


app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:4000/",
    ],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((error) => console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

My package.json file:

{
  "name": "diambackend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/mrpratik01/diamBackend.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mrpratik01/diamBackend/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mrpratik01/diamBackend#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "email-verifier": "^0.4.1",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.12",
    "mongoose": "8.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.13",
    "nvm": "^0.0.4",
    "shortid": "^2.2.16"
  }
}

I have tried all the method like changing node version and keeping same version as of my cpanel. Followed all the steps like npm install setting up the node js app, but after doing all the activity I am not being able run my backend properly; it is giving me 503 service unavailable. I want to run my API successfully when I enter the get method it should show the data after fetching it, but at the end it is giving me 503 service unavailable.
I am getting this error from the server error log messages

024-06-10 05:16:07.097415 [INFO] [22999] [T0] [23.111.175.170:16662#APVH_thediamlaundry.com] File not found [/home/thediamlaundry/public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge/ZW8EGK615A-KY064E2XXF9JYREN6O1OD]

